# How can I find and eliminate hidden processes running on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gcc, heroku, timeout

I have a CSV import that runs through a variety of processes on a list of roughly 11,000 names. The process is backgrounded, and the file itself can upload within 2.5 seconds.

The trouble however is that Heroku gives me an R12 Timeout for being past 30 seconds. The entire process hangs until I get an Application Error.

If I run `heroku logs`, nothing is being run at all. The app is completely flatlined.

But, I found that if I run `heroku restart`, then the file gets into resque and backgrounded in less than 5 seconds and everything works fine.

So I imagine there's some sort of used up memory. Is there a way to get stats on where these processes are being eaten up? I know Ruby has no manual GCC, but is it possible that something isn't getting garbage collected properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the runtime metrics logging, which frequently prints memory and CPU usage stats to the logs for each running process. That might give you some clue as to where the timeouts are coming from.

You can enable it like this:

```
$ heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics
$ heroku restart
```

See the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics#enabling) for more info.

Comment: Would you know of any heroku compiler's that can log all this information and relate it to actual processes?

Comment: The runtime metrics are shown per Heroku process, but I think that's as detailed as it gets.